# Getting an error but still changing value of key in app.config with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a very simple script to change a configuration key in my app.config using a powershell script like this

```
dir *.config -Recurse -PipelineVariable webconfig |
    ForEach {
        $doc = [xml] (Get-Content $_)
        $environment = $doc.configuration.appSettings.add | where {$_.Key -eq 'Environment'} 
        ($environment).value = "ci"
        $doc.Save($webconfig)     
    }
```

The problem is that when I run it I'm getting

```
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

At line:5 char:9

But if after running the script and getting that error I run the same script without the assignment, i.e.

```
dir *.config -Recurse -PipelineVariable webconfig |
    ForEach {
        $doc = [xml] (Get-Content $_)
        $environment = $doc.configuration.appSettings.add | where {$_.Key -eq 'Environment'} 
        ($environment).value
        $doc.Save($webconfig)     
    }
```

It actually displays the value properly changed (which is confirmed in the actual file).

So I'm lost here,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like this will fail when checking config files that don't include the environment app setting.  Try checking to see if $environment is not null before setting the value.

Comment: I have tried this but somehow it didn't work, was just doing             if(!environment){
                $environment.value = "ci"
                $doc.Save($webconfig)     
            } but I think you may be right because with just one file it works, so maybe the nullity check is not correct?

Comment: Correct, you are setting the value only when it is null. Try $environment -ne $null

Comment: That's pretty embarrassing, there are days when you shouldn't leave your bed. Thanks!!